# What formula would I use to count values in one cell, but only if another cell is blank?

Tags: excel, countif

Trying to get a count based on cells in two different columns - I want to count all cells in column A that have a value, but I only want these values to be counted if there is no value in a cell in column B
Ex. of what this would look like in Excel: A2 = 2020-08-19, B2 =
*B2 is blank

Current formula is below, just returns a FALSE. I've also tried a few variations of COUNTIFS, but can't seem to get it right.

=IF(ISBLANK(B2:B6),COUNTIF(A2:A6,"*"))

Answer (score 2):

Blanks get difficult with COUNTIFS, as an empty string(`""`) is different than a true blank to COUNTIFS, I would use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(A2:A6)>0)*(LEN(B2:B6)=0))
```

Comment: Thank you! I should've also mentioned I'm testing it in Excel to then put it into Data Studio. Your solution worked in Excel, but any ideas for bringing it into Data Studio?

Comment: Please do not change the question after receiving an answer.  If you need to, create a new post to ask the follow up question.  By changing the question you have invalidated my answer and exposed me to potential down votes.  This answered the original question.  please revert the question to the previous edit and ask a new question.